# Nodejs Express Generator

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I got some erros when I type npm start.
I create express-generator app with

**'express mynewapp' -> cd mynewapp -> npm install -> npm start.**

It should work but it gives this errors and I can't find solution. Here is my `CMD`

And this is my APP.js, I never change anything, It generated express-generator

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

[image]

Also the npm doctor

[Npm doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC5SU.png)

Comment: What does your app.js file look like ?!

Comment: maybe try deleting node_modules and re-install `rm -rf node_modules` and then install again `npm i`

Comment: I deleted and re-installed but it's same,Also I clean the cache and upgrade node

Comment: Most likely a https://github.com/dougwilson/nodejs-depd issue...

Comment: I don't know Why it's happening, am I doing something wrong

Comment: Any other suggestion